# How to deal with obsolete questions?

Tags: support

I recently [asked a question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047182/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-travis-ci-and-access-them-from-python-script/) and then found out that my mistake had nothing to do with what I expected. So the script posted in my question was perfectly valid and the mistake took place elsewhere in the setup.

Should I mark my question for deletion, accept my own answer, or what is the way to go here? Perhaps the (little) knowledge contained in my question could still be useful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You laboured under an illusion that (at least some) other Python developers will also labour under. Leave your question and answer so that anyone researching a similar situation will reach a solution more quickly. Your experience is valuable *precisely because* you were labouring under an illusion.

Answer (score 2):

If you find your question absolutely unnecessary, you should be able to delete your question by clicking the delete button.